# Radius server on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, radius

Is it possible to use Google App Engine as a Radius server?

Answer (score 3):

RADIUS uses UDP as a transport protocol.

It can NOT be implemented in App Engine as App Engine does not support UDP (or, more correctly, it does not expose UDP functionality to the developer).

Answer (score 1):

You probably can create a free account on Cloudessa RADIUS, which is run on AWS, and then access AWS from Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard someone using GAE to replace the mysql backend of FreeRadius. Not sure if this is what you want.

He uses rlm_python to run a python script, then communicate with GAE instance to authorize users.

Comment: Any chance in finding this person?  That sounds like what I am searching for right now for an ambitious little project I have.

Comment: @MindlessTux Actually I'm working on it myself now :-) You can refer to FreeRadius's source code. There's a example python script in the source tarball.